# Start up error after power outage

Tags: windows-7, windows, malware, login-items

I hooked up a Wi-Fi router today. About 20 minutes later the building power went off suddenly (not related to the router). When I tried to start the computer I got this message:

> There was a problem starting C:\users\lynn\appdata\local\conduit\backgroundcontainer\backgroundcontainer.dll

I also didn't have Internet access. I shut down and disconnected the router hooking up the modem only. I now have Internet access but continue to get the startup error.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backgroundcontainer.dll is a notorious malware, so it was probably removed by an antivirus. To remove the error, try this:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows logo] (Win)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `taskschd.msc`
3. Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
4. Click on the Task Scheduler Library folder
5. Right-click on the BackgroundContainer task
6. Select "Delete”

(Instructions originally by GreginMich on Microsoft Answers: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_other-protect_scanning/error-message-on-start-up-windows-8/7f29c7ad-2d55-4f1c-8110-ddca3902f596)

After this is done, update your antivirus' definitions and run a full PC scan to be safe.